# Generating test coverage reports only once within a GitHub Actions matrix

Tags: github-actions, codecov

I have a test suite that I want to run in a [matrix strategy](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstrategymatrix) using GitHub Actions. I want to generate a code coverage report for my tests, but *only* for a single matrix item.

Here is a copy of the action I'm working with:

```yaml
name: test
on: [pull_request, workflow_dispatch]
jobs:
  run_tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [14.x, 16.x]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        name: Test Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      - run: npm install --production=false
      - run: npm test -- --coverage ## I would prefer to only generate coverage once
      - name: Upload to Codecov     ## I would like to only run this once
        run: |
          curl -Os https://uploader.codecov.io/latest/linux/codecov
          chmod +x codecov
          ./codecov
```

Is it possible to only invoke the `Upload to Codecov` step only for one (could be final, or first) of the matrix strategy invocations? I'd like the solution to be general, rather than "if the value is 16.x", so that in future when we update the matrix versions we don't have to also update which version generates the report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can:

```yaml
- name: Upload to Codecov
  if: ${{ matrix.node-version }} == '16.x'
  run: |
      curl -Os https://uploader.codecov.io/latest/linux/codecov
      chmod +x codecov
      ./codecov
```

or

```yaml
- name: Upload to Codecov
  run: |
    if [[ $(node -v) == v16* ]]; then
      curl -Os https://uploader.codecov.io/latest/linux/codecov
      chmod +x codecov
      ./codecov
    fi
```